# List<Enum> contains String

Tags: java

I have a list of enums like the below -

```
List<Status> statusList;
```

Status is defined as below

```
enum Status { YES , NO , MAYBE }
```

The list contains

```
Status stat = Status.YES;
statusList.add(stat);
```

I have a variable

```
Status statusVar = Status.YES;
```

I am trying to a comparison like below but it is not working as I guess it is comparing the references. The below returns false. Can you please suggest a solution?

```
statusList.contains(statusVar)
```

EDIT: Below is the code that is not working. Status is string not Enum

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Test {
    private enum Status {
        YES , NO , MAYBE
    }


    public static void main (String[] args){

        List<Status> statusList = new ArrayList<Status>();
        String status = "YES";
        statusList.add(Status.YES);

        if(statusList.contains(status)){
            System.out.println(" Yes ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" No ");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example program](/help/mcve) which demonstrates the problem? As written, this should work.

Comment: The references are the same, so comparing the references is not the reason.

Comment: Are you trying to create a `List` from `enum` ?

Comment: My intuition say Set is better structure, but thread without sources isn't clear

Comment: Apologies for the confusion,  looked closely and saw that I am trying to check if a string is in enum list.

Comment: A String is never equal to an enum: they're not the same type. You can use `if(statusList.contains(Status.valueOf(status))){` to transform the string into the corresponding enum.

Comment: Is there was to use contains or should iterate over each and every element and convert it to string before comparing?

Comment: Thanks JB , this works fine!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are performing a contains, it will be much more efficient if you use an `EnumSet`

```
Set<Status> status = EnumSet.of(Status.YES);
assert status.contains(Status.YES);
```

However, `List<Status>` will also work.

You are right it does compare the reference, but this will only fail if you have

- multiple ClassLoaders and the Class `Status` is actually different.
- you create new instances of the `Status` which you can do using `Unsafe.allocateInstance(Status.class)`

What is more likely is you are not testing what you think you are and the situation isn't exactly as you have described.

Answer (score 2):

```
private enum Status {
    YES , NO , MAYBE
    ;
    public Status getByName(String name){
        for (Status st : Status.values()) {
            if (st.toString().equals(name)){
                return st;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

try this!

Comment: I do not know the Status.valueOf (status), perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a function toString() and contains() as helpers:

```
private enum Status {
    YES("Yes") , NO ("Yes") , MAYBE("Yes");
    private final String label;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Status.
     * @param label the label
     */
    private Status (final String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }

    public static boolean contains(final String test) {

        for (final Status value : Status.values()) {
            if (value.toString().equals(test)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Status { YES , NO , MAYBE }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Status> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(Status.YES);

    Status stat = Status.YES;

    System.out.println(lista.contains(Status.YES));//true
    System.out.println(lista.contains(stat));//true

}
```

I made this code and print both ways and it worked perfectly

or

you remembered to instantiate the variable statusList

Comment: generics in runtime do not cause errors, and populate with String, is it?